# PnP provisioning engine not updating structural navigation

Tags: flow, azure, pnp, template

Anyone have any ideas on why my PnP [Provisioning engine](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/introducing-the-pnp-provisioning-engine) isn't updating any of the structural navigation after the template is applied?

```
<pnp:StructuralNavigation RemoveExistingNodes="false">
        <pnp:NavigationNode Title="Home" Url="{site}" />
        <pnp:NavigationNode Title="Strategy" Url="{site}/Strategy" />
        <pnp:NavigationNode Title="Documents" Url="{site}/Documents" />
        <pnp:NavigationNode Title="Administration" Url="{site}/Administration" IsExternal="true" />
        <pnp:NavigationNode Title="Documents" Url="{site}/Documents" IsExternal="true" />
        <pnp:NavigationNode Title="Working Files" Url="{site}/Working Files" />
        <pnp:NavigationNode Title="Reviews" Url="{site}/Reviews" />
        <pnp:NavigationNode Title="Graphics" Url="{site}/Graphics" />
        <pnp:NavigationNode Title="Pricing" Url="{site}/Pricing" IsExternal="true" />
</pnp:StructuralNavigation>
```

When I manually apply the template everything works and updates fine. But the minute I fire this thing through azure and flow the structural navigation does not load.

I do not get any errors in the logs on azure or in flow errors.

Comment: When you test the script locally, how are you authenticating? Same question about the Azure. Can you try running the script locally, using the same authentication as Azure does and see if it works? I had noticed before that some types of authentications cause weird issues in PnP provisioning templates.